# Dgrid FilteringSelect Editor with conditional options based on dgrid content

Tags: dojo, editor, store, dropdownbox, dgrid

How can I specify different FilteringSelect Option contents per row based on the data or condition in different column of the grid? The Filtering Select is created in Dgrid ColumnSets.

Example:
I have 2 sets of stores, store1 and store2
Filtering select is placed on Col2

If Col1 = ConditionA, then set filtering select store to Store1
If Col1 = ConditionB, then set filtering select store to Store2